# Integral as a "function" - but in which variable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I hope my question is not too silly.

If I have an integral as
$$
\int_x^\infty K(x,y)X(y)\, dy
$$
is this a function in $x$ or a function in $y$?

I think this can be seen as
$$
J(x)=\int_x^\infty K(x,y)X(y)\, dy,
$$
i.e. as a function in $x$.

Comment: You're right. The variable y is integrated out.

Comment: (Not silly at all.  I remember being confused over many questions like this one.  And Sean Roberson and you are correct, BTW.)